# In Keynote, how to change no-fill color from black to something else?

Tags: macos, keynote

Using MacOS Keynote, I'm exporting animated graphics with transparent backgrounds. For example, the graphic may be black and white such as this:

[image]

But to make the background of the slide transparent, the background is set to no-fill which causes the background to be black:

[image]

So to work with files with black text or artwork (everything I do), the background color must be repeatedly flipped between fill color and no-fill. Is there a way to set the default for the no-fill color to something else than black such as gray?:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do this with Keynote on iOS or macOS? Also, just to clarify, are you trying to change the background color of the slide or the image?

Comment: Good point. I forgot about the iOS version. The question was edited to clarify that Mac OS is the platform. I was hoping to make the 'transparent' background of the slide some color other than black.

Comment: I have gone through all of the Keynote files including property lists looking for a flag. Considered using Applescript to automate a fill/no-fill switch but didn't get far with that.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the object of interest and on top right click on format. The in the right sidebar click on style. The sidebar should look as shown below. Directly above the "No fill" pulldown is a box with a red diagonal line (shown with a blue rectangle around it). Click on that box and select your color.

[image]

Comment: When I change the color there, the no-fill becomes a color fill. I want to keep the background of the slide as transparent(no-fill) but, in doing so, the transparent background of the slide is always black, making further work difficult. I'd like transparent to show as gray or neon green or something other than black, if possible.

Comment: I don’t quite understand why the background needs to be transparent. It’s black because it has to have a color since there is nothing behind it. If you want the color to be gray or neon green, you can set the background color to it; this shouldn't have an effect on the image by doing this.

Comment: I'm exporting numerous animated gifs with transparent backgrounds and have set "Export with transparent backgrounds" but this "Applies only when slide background is set to No Fill or has transparency." So it seems I'm stuck frequently changing the background to a color fill to see what I'm drawing and then to no fill for export. That isn't a problem for a few images but I'm working with large numbers, often with many revisions. Just would like to improve this workflow if possible. Black for transparency seems a rather unfortunate choice considering how many images use black.